# Install two applications with the same name?

Tags: software-installation

I have installed [an application for data recovery](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/) called "R studio" (rstudio 2.0.377). Now I want to install another unrelated application for [an IDE of R programming language](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop) also called "R studio" (rstudio 0.97.551), by opening its .deb file in software center, but the software center says "A later version already installed", and I can't find a way to proceed.  How can I install them both on my Ubuntu 12.04? Thanks!

Comment: I have this exact same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see both deb install different files and folder...
but the problem could be that these applications have the same name in the "control" file under the debian package.

You can try changing the name of the package, open a Terminal when you have the deb package and type the following:

- Unpack the rstudio-0.97.551-amd64.deb in a temp folder.

`dpkg-deb -x rstudio-0.97.551-amd64.deb tempdeb`

`dpkg-deb --control rstudio-0.97.551-amd64.deb tempdeb/DEBIAN`

- Go to the tempdeb/DEBIAN folder en edit the file "control" and change the name of the package from "rstudio" to "rstudio-ide"

`gedit tempdeb/DEBIAN/control`

[image]

- Repack the .deb, in this case with other name.

`dpkg -b tempdeb new-rstudio-ide-0.97.551-amd64.deb`

- As the [Web site](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/desktop) says.. you need to install r-base

`sudo apt-get install r-base`

- Then you can install the new deb package

`sudo dpkg -i new-rstudio-ide-0.97.551-amd64.deb`

You should have both applications installed and running...

[image]

[image]

To remove this package use this command:

`sudo dpkg --purge rstudio-ide`

Hope this will helpful.